# Googlefinance - return high price AND date

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I'm using `GOOGLEFINANCE` formula to retrieve highest values and relative date for a stock from a given period.

For example: `=GOOGLEFINANCE(AAPL,"HIGH",08/5/2020,08/11/2020)` return the following results:

```
Date, High
8/5/2020 16:00:00, 441.57
8/6/2020 16:00:00, 457.65
8/7/2020 16:00:00, 454.7
8/10/2020 16:00:00, 455.1
8/11/2020 16:00:00, 449.93
```

At the moment I have

```
=MAX(INDEX((GOOGLEFINANCE(AAPL,"HIGH",08/5/2020,08/11/2020)),0,1))
```

In this way I get the highest value (`457.65` in the example), but i still miss the `date` associated with it, on a separate cell (`8/6/2020`).

How can I get the date too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "HIGH", "8/5/2020", "8/11/2020"), 2, 0), 2)
```

[image]